# How to align <li> to the top when higher items are hidden via CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an `<ul>` to do a menu bar. The bar is vertical on the left of my screen. When an option is selected out of the first visible section, I will use `JS` to hide the first block and set the remaining blocks to `.show()`

on the next chunk based on the option selected. Now, I have no problem with the `JS` portion of this. My problem is - when I `.hide()` and `.show()` the `<li>` groups, they stay as if the others were present (large gaps in between options vs top aligned).

Here is a sample of my list:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a id="mainSuit" href="javascript: void(0)">Suit</a></li>
    <li><a id="mainFinances" href="javascript: void(0)">Finances</a></li>
    <li><a id="mainMissions" href="javascript: void(0)">Missions</a></li>
    <li><a id="mainTerritory" href="javascript: void(0)">Territory</a></li>
    <li><a id="mainCompany" href="javascript: void(0)">Company</a></li>
    <li><a id="mainTravel" href="javascript: void(0)">Travel</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- More <ul> between the two -->

<ul class="menu">
    <li><a id="suitLoadout">Loadout</a></li>
    <li><a id="suitEquipment">Equipment Market</a></li>
    <li><a id="suitMunitions">Munitions Surplus</a></li>
    <li><a id="suitRefuel">Refuel</a></li>
    <li><a id="suitRepair">Repair</a></li>
</ul>
```

For CSS

```
#suitRepair {
    display: none;
}

/* same for all of the IDs */
```

So when id **mainSuit** is selected - all of `<ul class="menu">` will be hidden and the section for suit is shown.

How would I get it so that any gaps for UL blocks between these too are removed.

Comment: Are you using the jquery $.hide and $.show on the ul elements or the li elements?

Comment: @Phil_1984_ both, but not on initilization of the page - I think I'll try it that way.

Comment: I think your problem lies with the margins of the UL.  When you hide all the LI elements you are left with essentially an empty UL which will have a bit of margin.  I recommend you .hide and .show the whole UL elements rather than the individual LI elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Even better - use the `<ul>` as the identifier and go that route:

```
<ul id="mainMenu">
    <li id="mainSuit"><a onclick="mainSuit()" href="javascript: void(0)">Suit</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="suitMenu">
    <li id="suitLoadout"><a>Loadout</a></li>
    <li id="suitEquipment"><a>Equipment Market</a></li>
    <li id="suitMunitions"><a>Munitions Surplus</a></li>
    <li id="suitRefuel"><a>Refuel</a></li>
    <li id="suitRepair"><a>Repair</a></li>
</ul>
```

With `JS` of:

```
function backSelected() {
    $("#mainMenu").show();
    $("#suitMenu").hide();
}
function mainSuit() {
    $("#mainMenu").hide();
    $("#suitMenu").show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just try specify the id on < li > instead < a >:

```
<li><a id="suitLoadout">Loadout</a></li>
```

will be:

```
<li id="suitLoadout"><a>Loadout</a></li>
```

Now you will hide the < li > tag not the content of that tag, so the space gap will be solved ;)